# Reporting a typo/incorrect code in Notepad v1 example 1 on the Android Developers site

Tags: android, notepad

On the Android developers website, there is [a Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) and I found a mistake in the first example. After browsing through the site, I cannot find a way to report it to anyone.

The mistake is in "Step 4" of Example 1, when defining the notepad_list layout file.  The tutorial has you type in the ListView and TextView id's as "@android:id/id_name".  However, upon completing the rest of the steps and running this (it compiles fine), pressing the Menu button to add a note causes the app to close.  Comparing this file with the solution provided (which works fine), I see that the entry should in fact be written as "@id/android:id_name".

I would like to report this typo to the creator or manager of the tutorial so that the walkthrough can be edited but I can't find any sort of contact or way to do so on the website.

Does anyone know how I can go about getting this fixed for future beginning developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:id="@android:id/list" is correct.

the @android:id is used in place of @id when it is system specified tag. For instance, a ListActivity requires @android:id/list to be present in the layout

Comment: So why does the app not run correctly with the first option, and why does the solution provided use something different than what is given in the tutorial?

Comment: I went through the tutorial step-by-step and everything worked fine...could you provide your layout xml and activity code to help diagnose what went wrong?

Comment: Ok, I'll post it when I get home.  To add another dimension to this problem, on my work system it seems to run fine either way, but I first observed this problem on my system at home.  Maybe my Eclipse install at home is an older version compared to what I'm running at work?  Maybe the ADT plugin needs updating?  I'll edit the main post with the code if I can reproduce the issue at home again, along with details on my system.  If I can't reproduce the issue when I get home, I'll let this die.

Comment: Ok, I got home and launched it right away without changing anything.  Now it works.  I can't explain it.  I keep my Workspace on Dropbox so I know the project is exactly the same on the two systems.  Thanks for your time and thanks for reading through.

Comment: @android:id/list does not work for me. The application crashes. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions: http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: This is correct procedure, however what he lists is not a bug.